# Docker volume clears folder in container on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've created a simple docker with a nodejs server.

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY ./app/package.json .
RUN yarn

COPY ./app ./app
```

This works great and the service is running.

Now I'm trying to run the docker with a volume for local development using docker compose:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
    web:
        image: my-node-app
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: ["yarn", "start"]        
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./app/Dockerfile
```

This is my folder structure in the host:

[image]

The service works without the volume. When I add the volume, the /usr/src/app is empty (even though it is full as shown in the folder structure).

Inspecting the docker container I get the following mount config:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/d/development/dockerNCo/app",
            "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
            "Mode": "rw",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

But still, browsing to the folder via shell of vscode show it as empty.

In addition, the command: `docker volume ls` shows an empty list.

I'm running docker 18.09.3 on windows 10.

Is there anything wrong with the configuration? How is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the volume to your service will remove all the files `/usr/src/app` and mount the content of  `./app` from your host machine. This also means that all files generated by running `yarn` in the docker image will be lost because they exist only in the docker image. This is the expected behaviour of adding volume in docker and it is not a bug.

```
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
```

- Usually and for none development Envs you don't need the volume at all here.
- If you would like to see the files on your host, you need to run `yarn` command from docker-compose (you can use an entry point)

Comment: I actually see the node modules, as they are generated in the /usr/src folder.
The problem is - I don't see the files in the `/usr/src/app` folder even though the exist in the `./app` host.

Comment: is this `/d/development/dockerNCo/app` the correct path for `./app`  ?

Comment: Yes. I think the problem stems from a windows permissions issue.
The config seems fine and I'm using it on other machines.
I guess docker cannot fully function in a windows home version :(

Comment: if you are running this on windows, you need to add the correct path. here is the link that describes how to do this https://adamtheautomator.com/docker-volumes-windows/

Comment: Thanks. I've tried what's written in this article before (I've been struggling with this issue for a day now). It's not working. The thing is - the path in the source is correct. It seems like a permissions issue.